# My Stack is losing its value when I redirect to another controller

Tags: c#

I have tried this using a List and it retains the value fine, but when i change it to a stack the value is lost. I have been stepping through but I can't understand why its gone.

​

```
 public ActionResult AddToOrder()
        {
            //Get logged in student from db
            var student = _db.Students.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            //Create a new Order
            var order = new Order();

            //add all elements from Student collection to Order collection
            foreach (var app in student.Applications)
            {
                order.Applications.Add(app);
            }

            //assign order FK 
            order.StudentId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            //Push the order to the students Stack collection 
            student.Orders.Push(order); //(When the Student implements a List collection the value 
                                    //passes to the Stripe controller with no problems)

            //add order to db & save changes
            _db.Orders.Add(order);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            //redirect to stripe controller
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Stripe");

        }

        //STRIPE CONTROLLER
         public ActionResult Create(string stripeToken)
        {
            var student = _db.Students.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            student.Orders.Count // = 0 with Stack
                                 // = 1 with List
        }
```

The only thing I change is Stack to List in the Student entity and push to add.  Anybody any ideas whats going on?

I guess I could achieve what I want (LIFO) by using a list in this way. I would still like to know what's going on with my stack though.

myList.Insert(0, order) - - - my List.First()

Comment: where's the list defined? where is the stack defined?

Comment: In the Student entity.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Student` is an Entity Framework entity - an object representation of a database table. Its `Orders` property represents a relationship to another table. When you add order objects to a `Student`'s `Orders` property, Entity Framework does a *ton* of stuff under the hood to make sure that all of the object data is correctly written to the database as table data, with all of the proper foreign keys and such, when you call `SaveChanges`. Same thing when you call `Students.Find`: There's a lot of stuff going on to translate your code to a SQL query, run it, then turn the resulting SQL table data into a convenient `Student` object.

Entity Framework does all of that automatically, but in order for it to work, entity classes like `Student` need to be defined in a particular way such that EF knows how to handle them. To put it succinctly: properties like `Orders` that represent relationships to another table need to be `List`s. When you redefine `Student.Orders` to be a `Stack`, the Entity Framework machinery breaks, and EF can no longer use `Orders` to work with that portion of the database.

When your app redirects from one controller to another, the orders data is not retained in memory in the app, only in the database. When the target controller loads, your code is trying to load the data from the database that the previous controller was supposed to have saved there. One of two things is happening:

- Your change to use `Stack` broke the `Students` entity such that the data doesn't get saved to the database at all, OR
- Entity Framework can manage to handle `Stack` well enough to *save* the data, but not *load* it.

I'm not sure which is happening with this particular change, but either one is undesirable.

`Orders` needs to be a `List`. If you need to preserve some kind of ordering to the list, that needs to be explicit within the data model so that it ends up in the database. Maybe your `Order` class needs a `LineNumber` property or something similar. If you do something like that, keep in mind that both the code *and* the database have to be updated. Search for "Entity Framework migrations" for information about that, and ask a separate question if you get stuck on it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. Massive help.